# What does &# mean in HTML?

Tags: html, css

```
<form>
  <p>How much was your bill?
  <p>
    $ <input id="billamt" type="text" placeholder="Bill Amount">

  <p>How was your service?
  <p>
    <select id="serviceQual">
      <option disabled selected value="0">-- Choose an Option --</option>
      <option value="0.3">30&#37; &#45; Outstanding</option>
      <option value="0.2">20&#37; &#45; Good</option>
      <option value="0.15">15&#37; &#45; It was OK</option>
      <option value="0.1">10&#37; &#45; Bad</option> 
      <option value="0.05">5&#37; &#45; Terrible</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Code from Carolyn hemmings tip calculator

Comment: This docs can help you understand HTML Entities https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp

Answer (score 2):

From [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#character-references):

> Decimal numeric character reference
>
> The ampersand must be followed by a U+0023 NUMBER SIGN character (#), followed by one or more ASCII digits, representing a base-ten integer that corresponds to a code point that is allowed according to the definition below. The digits must then be followed by a U+003B SEMICOLON character (;).

Answer (score 0):

Those are html entries. I can't explain clearly here. you may read about this from w3schools.com you may use this link. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp
more about display html symbols.  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp